# Script file for executing adb command

Tags: android, shell, adb

We are making our application system app by moving the apk to system dir and restarting the device. In order to do this, need to run couple of adb commands.

In the production stage we cannot ask the client to run all these commands from their system. So i wanted to know is there any was i can run an script file which will do all these processes for me.

Commands i need to execute:

```
adb root
adb remount
adb push /sdcard/download/base.apk /system/priv-app/
adb shell chmod 644 /system/priv-app/base.apk
adb reboot
```

And is it possible to run a script file without the help of any third-party application ?

Comment: Sure you can put those commands in a script file. Are you using a Linux system? Just create a shell script file and put those ADB commands in it. It would help if you clarify your question. You want to run a shell script on a Linux system to execute ADB commands on a device connected by USB?

Comment: @EricB Can i run the script file from the mobile without the help of system ?

Comment: I'm assuming that the mobile is the system you are connecting to with ADB. If that is true, no. You can not run the script from the mobile.

Comment: If you want to run those ADB commands on the phone you need to try to find the equivalent shell command. For example. "adb remount" might be "adb shell mount -o remount,rw /system". Then you could put all of those shell commands in to a shell script on the mobile phone. Or, you could put them all in one adb shell command separated by semicolons (;).